# mysql insert into host table when matching username and uid found in user table

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a command line script to insert users into a host table. But I want to only allow the add to host when the username and UID match that of the username and uid in the user table.

I have this.. Which works fine... [even without the INTO]

```
doquery2() {                                                                                                                              
mysql -e "$query2" -h $DBHOST --password=******* userdb

}                                                         


INSERT hosts SET hostname=\"$HostName\",                                                                                          
username=\"$UserName\",                                                                                                                   
password=\"$Password\",                                                                                                                   
UID=\"$zUID\",                                                                                                                            
GID=\"$zGID\",                                                                                                                            
Full_Name=\"${FullName:=empty}\",                                                                                                         
Homedir=\"${HomeDir:=empty}\",                                                                                                            
Default_shell=\"${DefaultShell:=empty}\""
```

But I want to add the lookup from the user table and only add to host when username and UID match.

Any ideas?